# Creating a deskop application using vaadin or zkoss framework

Tags: vaadin, zk

Can we create a desktop application using zkoss or vaadin framework ?

If so, please explain how can i create it with some examples.

Comment: AFAIK, Vaadin is WebFramework, no way you can build a desktop application with it.

Comment: There is something called ZK Spring may it can help [link](http://www.zkoss.org/documentation/zkspring#Getting_Started)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can create an ".exe" that will launch your Vaadin application in a standalone mode.

But I think that you can follow these steps :

- Create a Vaadin application with an embeddable server (like Jetty)
- Then, open your application with a browser (obviously) and export the app as a Web Application. This feature exists on Google Chrome (Menu > Tools > Create application shortcuts ... ) or on Firefox (through the Prism add-on).